# C# how to remove last line from a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

i wrote a code that is working fine.
however there is something annoying me.
Here is the code

```
        string secretWord = "ola";
        string guess;
        int counter = 4;

        Console.WriteLine("Try to guess a secret word that contain 3 character. You have 4 attemps");

        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            guess = Console.ReadLine();

            if (guess == secretWord)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Well done! You guessed correctly");
                break;
            }
            else if (guess.Length != 3)
            {
                counter--;
                Console.WriteLine("Only three characters. You lost one attempt");
                Console.WriteLine("You have now {0} attempts", counter);
            }
            else if (guess != secretWord)
            {
                counter--;
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong. you have now {0} attempts", counter);
            }
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad lucky. The secret word is {0}", secretWord);
            }
        }
```

What is annoying me is that if the user make it wrong the 4 times.
after the last one is showing

"Wrong. You have now 0 attempts"

"Bad lucky. the secret word is ola"

There is some how i can remove this line 
"Wrong. you have now 0 attempts"
??

Thank you all
[image]

Comment: actually in the for loop is (int i = 0; i<4 (instead 3); i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the last `else if` in this way

```
 else if (guess != secretWord)
        {
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("Bad lucky. The secret word is {0}", secretWord);
                  break;
               }

            Console.WriteLine("Wrong. you have now {0} attempts", counter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reverting the order and changing the last else if i as suggested by Stefano it was possible to solve my problem.